# User Authentication through API using IdentityServer4

Tags: identityserver4

I'm looking into `IdentityServer4` as a possible solution for managing users and API access tokens. One thing that is not clear is if it's possible to provide authentication through API calls or are we forced to use a login page hosted by `IdentityServer4`?

With respect to user experience in mobile apps, it's always nicer to provide a simple login screen within the app, as opposed to opening a web page that handles the login process.

Are we forced to use a login / registration page hosted by `IdentityServer4` or can it be handled through API calls?

Comment: You don't have to redirect, to IdentityServer if you host identityserver in your api.  However alot of the time people like to keep their token servers seperate from the API, because having a token server implies you have multiple applications, and you can only 1 api can host the token server,  Alternatively you could just forward your request from the server, and just use a simple login page in your api

Comment: The scenario I'd be interested in is to have `IdentityServer4` as a separate app that resides on its own domain e.g. `login.mydomain.com` so that it can serve multiple apps.

Comment: I set something similar up with one of my applications.  You a have a few options,  You can provide a way for Identity Server to template your login page, so the on hosted on Identity server matches your application, and you can provide a template per application and host it in an IFrame.  Alternatively, you can just forward the username password credentials, and have your api obtain the oauth token for you, but that slightly breaks security paradigms of OAuth,  With authorization code you then integrity of your password is tied to the identity server only

Comment: but with the resource owner grant method, your password will be passing through the api as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Login should occur on the IdentityServer website for the simple reason that a *client can't be trusted* with the user credentials.

When the user logs in on the IdentityServer website, the client remains ignorant of the credentials. The user is either authenticated or the request is rejected.

Please note that an embedded browser for a 'good user experience' is also not recommended, as this will require the user to enter the credentials in an unsafe environment (credentials could be captured), even when the IdentityServer website is shown.

For user experience you can use the client_id and acr_values for additional parameters to customize the login page on IdentityServer.

Comment: Yup! It seems there’s an inverse correlation between UX and security :-) I guess, by the same token, all those mobile apps with built-in login screens are insecure by definition.

Comment: These are worth a read: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc8252 and https://auth0.com/blog/oauth-2-best-practices-for-native-apps/

Comment: All sorts of positives to using the browser for authentication - e.g. support for 2FA, federation and WebAuthn/FIDO2 becomes possible and the client app need not be aware of them at all. It also means that the user's browser-integrated password manager will just work.

Answer (score 0):

Reading from the [documentation](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/topics/signin.html) it's sufficient to have an API call to the server. 
On the server side there will be a back-end running developed using the IdentityServer framework, this will handle the login / registration API calls.

As reference implementation you can have a look on the official [demo](https://demo.identityserver.io/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2Fgrants) and inspect the Network calls.

Comment: The part that is throwing me off and doubt that this is possible is the workflow. Here's the exact verbiage from their documentation: When IdentityServer receives a request at the authorization endpoint and the user is not authenticated, the user will be redirected to the configured login page. You must inform IdentityServer of the path to your login page via the UserInteraction settings on the options (the default is /account/login).

Comment: So looks like it's not as simple as sending username/password pair to an API endpoint on `IdentityServer4`. There seems to be a few redirects going on first.